# Correct way to submit form with ENTER key with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the 3 HTML inputs, 2 which receive user input and one which displays a calculation once a button named #calculate is pressed. The following piece of code will correctly perform the calculation upon the clicking of the #calculate button, but I am looking for the most efficient way to have the form submit the form when the user enters the ENTER/RETURN key in addition of clicking on the button with mouse.

```
                $('#calculate').click(function(){
                var count = 0;
                count += checkRequired('#field_3_a');
                count += checkRequired('#field_3_b');

                if (count == 0)//enough data
                {
                    //calculate
                    var a = parseFloat($('#field_3_a').val());
                    var b = parseFloat($('#field_3_b').val());
                    var totalValue = (b - a) / a  * 100;
                    $('#result_3').val(totalValue);
                }
            });
```

Your input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the `keypress` event on the text fields, or the form, and check if the key pressed was `enter`:

```
$('#field_3_a, #field_3_b').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //do something, like call calculate()
    }
});
```